# Are Boots of Mobility viable on Varus?

Tags: league-of-legends

Are Boots of Mobility viable on Varus? Since he has no escape mechanism other than his ult would having a greater passive speed prove to be most useful out of all the other boots?

Comment: subjective question really

Comment: @Paralytic so? It'a a subjective question that can be answered well and backed up with evidence. See also: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz o right guess i'm the only one that asks subjective questions

Comment: If the real question is "how can I gain more survivability as Varus", edit it to that, at present this question's answer would be different from varus player to varus player and from one skill level to another

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say "not really".

Boots of mobility give you a chance of escaping if you weren't actually fighting.

If you are going to escape from someone, either back off while your team does their job and defends you.

If you mean "escaping" such as "pushing a tower with 5 MIA and run away before they get you", i'd rather go with Boots of Something Else with an Alacrity enchant.

Comment: Ok, will fix answer when got more time